# Replace a value of parameter in a file

Tags: linux

I have a multiple files named `paramaters.txt` containing different parameters and their values:

```
param1 = vaue1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3
```

And I'd like to replace value of `param2` and have

```
param1 = vaue1
param2 = value4
param3 = value3
```

I was trying to use `sed` but I was able to do it if I know the string I want to replace, `value2` in my case. But I don't know it (or rather it can be different in different files).
I would rather try to find string `param2` and replace everything that is on the right side of it.
But I don't know how to do it.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish what you want is to use `sed` to find the line with the parameter you want and replace the entire line. Something like this should work:

```
sed -i 's/^param2 =.*/param2 = value4/' file
```